# Listview not showing results

Tags: android, listview

I am struggling with showing results in a listview. So here is my application in short:

First screen -> Different activities to perform and search is one of them. Once User chooses Search, next screen has an input box and two buttons. Based on input keyword, I search for results and want to show results on the next screen, but my next screen appears ,but the results don't appear. Here is some code from my app

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchcriteria);

        txtSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchstring);
        btnCurrentLoc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.currentlocation);

        btnCurrentLoc.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                setContentView(R.layout.searchresults);
                String keyword = txtSearch.getText().toString();
                performSearch(keyword);                         
            }
        });
    }

private void performSearch(String searchterm){
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Search.this, "Please wait......", "Retrieving data ....",true,true);
        PerformSearchTask task = new PerformSearchTask();
        task.execute(searchterm);
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new CancelTaskOnCancelListener(task));       
    }

private class PerformSearchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Event>>{       

        @Override
        protected List<Event> doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            String query = arg0[0];
            return eventGetter.find(query);
        } 

        protected void onPostExecute(final List<Event> result){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                public void run() {
                    if(progressDialog != null){
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }
                    if(result != null){
                        Vector<String> ve = new Vector<String>();
                        for(Event event: result){
                            ve.add(event.title + "\n" + event.eventlocation + "\t" + event.eventdate);
                        }
                        String[] eventArray = new String[ve.size()];
                        for(int i = 0; i < ve.size(); i++){
                            eventArray[i] = ve.get(i);
                        }

                        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search.this,R.layout.searchresults,eventArray));

                    }

                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Searchresults' screen layout is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/resultsofsearch"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativelayout_1"
android:layout_width="320px"
android:layout_height="332px"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/back"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Back"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/info"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Info"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>
</Button>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1.0"
android:layout_below="@+id/back"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: have you debugged the application to see where it fails?

Comment: Please also post the XML for the layout code.

Comment: @Stephan - I added the layout. @Rajath - It is not failing, I get the data in my array and I set the adapter for listview, my screen for searchresults show up, but there are not results shown in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think u should implement each button click in separate Activity. it should solve ur problem Try this...Let me know if any difficulties occur

Comment: I am going to try this, but this is not always optimum solution.

Comment: Thanks it helped, I figured out that I really don't need that runnable object. Some misunderstanding with Asynctask, I had.